# iOS: How to send image data periodically via socket?

Tags: ios, sockets

I am able to connect my iOS program to a java based socket listener and get it connected well. iOS app is also able to send screen shot image data to the socket very well. This is done under `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`

My problem is, i do not know, how to send this screenshot image periodically to the socket. I am sending it just once now, its working. But, i want to keep sending this image data to socket one after another screenshot taken programmatically in every certain interval. How to do that? Please advise.

Please refer my complete code below.

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    NSString *io;
    if (theStream == inputStream) io = @">>";
    else io = @"<<";

    NSString *event;
    switch (streamEvent)
    {
        case NSStreamEventNone:
            event = @"NSStreamEventNone";
            //statusText.text =  @"Can not connect to the host!";
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventNone - Can not connect to the host");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            event = @"NSStreamEventOpenCompleted";
            //pingButton.hidden = NO;
            //statusText.text = @"Connected";
            NSLog(@"Connected");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            event = @"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable";
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable called");
            if (theStream == inputStream)
            {
                //read data
                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;
                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable])
                {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0)
                    {
                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                        NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len];
                        if (nil != output)
                        {
                            //do something with data
                            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable theData: %@", theData);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            event = @"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable";

            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable called");

            NSLog(@"space : %d",[outputStream hasSpaceAvailable]);

            if (theStream == outputStream)
        {
                 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(appDelegate.window.bounds.size);
                [appDelegate.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
                UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                [data writeToFile:@"screenshot.png" atomically:YES];

                int num = [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
                if (-1 == num) {
                    NSLog(@"Error writing to stream %@: %@", outputStream, [outputStream streamError]);
                }else{
                    NSLog(@"Wrote %i bytes to stream %@.", num, outputStream);
                    //[outputStream close];
                }
        }
            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            event = @"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred";
            //statusText.text = @"Can not connect to the host!";
            //pingButton.hidden = YES;
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred - Can not connect to the host");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            event = @"NSStreamEventEndEncountered";
            //statusText.text = @"Connection closed by the server.";
            //pingButton.hidden = YES;
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventEndEncountered - Connection closed by the server");
            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            //[theStream release];
            theStream = nil;
            break;

        default:
            event = @"** Unknown";
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ : %@", io, event);
}
```

Under a Button click, the below code is for connecting the host initially.

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];

CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);
```

Comment: Can someone guide me, how can send data to socket server one after another thru iOS app?

Comment: I have fixed. It was required to have Socket Java code on the Socket listener end, not on the iOS client side. I have added Scanner class like "Scanner in;" class on the socket listener java program and added "while (in.hasNext())" for thread which is running for listening, so its not stopping the listener now, it will keep on listening for clients stream request.

Comment: I'm getting infinite loop for NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable case. What might be reason? Also code doesn't enters NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable section.